# logstash & kibana setting the @message property

Tags: logstash

The @message property seems to be the core property when using logstash & kibana. My json logger sends the data with the message at

```
{"msg":"some one did something"}
```

if i change it so its

```
 {"@message":"someone did something"}
```

the logstash server picks it up as "@fields.@message".

I am a bit confused how I can set this property to render correctly.

Comment: What input are you using?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that the input is reading events as `json` and not `json_event`. The difference is that `json` will add any fields under the @fields namespace. `json_event` will expect the full logstash event serialized as json.

The functionality you have is probably what you want. You typically don't want to be sending the full json_event if you don't have to. You can overwrite the @message field in logstash with the mutate filter.

```
mutate {
  type => 'json_logger'
  replace => ["@message", "%{msg}"]
  remove => "msg"
}
```